# Not a valid choice: Can't select ReferenceProperty value at SelectField wtform

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tipfy, wtforms

i try to use ReferenceProperty at form for create/edit Entry but nothing happen.

i have:

```
class Type(db.Model):
    name        = db.StringProperty()



class Entry(db.Model):
    type            = db.ReferenceProperty(Type, required=False)

class EntryForm(Form):
    _type_list = []
    for type in Type.all():
        _type_list.append((type.key(),type.name))
    type            = fields.SelectField(u'Type of entry', choices = _type_list)
```

and edit handler:

```
def post(self, **kwargs):
    self.form = EntryForm(self.request.form)
    if self.form.validate():
        values = {
            'type': models.Type.get_by_key_name(self.form.type.data).key(),
        }
        entry = Entry(**values)
        entry.put()
```

but i always have: Not a valid choice

Does enyone know how to work with ReferenceProperty  in wtforms SelectField or may you have working sample for this?

Comment: On what line do you get that error?

Comment: So you probably get it on the line with the if statement. Are the choices displayed properly and do you select one? The SelectField.pre_validate seems to raise the exception if the field data is not part of the possible choices. (http://code.google.com/p/tipfy/source/browse/source/lib/wtforms/fields.py?r=d5bfbedf3a33f23da014db73a41c82fbf4b10393)

Comment: i have "Not a valid choice" at form validation, when ii try to save selected value. Yes value displayed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem with this changes at Form class:

```
class EntryForm(Form):
    _type_list = []
    for type in Type.all():
        _type_list.append((type.key().id(),type.name))
    type            = fields.SelectField(u'Type of entry', choices = _type_list, coerce=int)
```

and edit handler:

```
def post(self, **kwargs):
    self.form = EntryForm(self.request.form)
    if self.form.validate():
        values = {
            'type': models.Type.get_by_id(self.form.type.data),
        }
        entry = Entry(**values)
        entry.put()
```

But if anyone know more elegant solution, you are welcome!